# create a table with composed primary keys

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table:

```
course
---------
id_course
id_groupe (references a table named group)
id_module (references a table named module)
```

In my case a course can be shared by many groups.

My question is :

- it is correct to  choose the primary key composed of (id_course , id_group )?
- and is there any other way to make the same table ?

Comment: i am working with oracle 11g..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that the course has another attribute - its title.

Ask yourself the question:

> Will the title of the course change if it is being taken by a member of "group A" or "group B"?

For most institutions, a course will have a set title and it does not matter who is taking that course so with your table structure you will have to duplicate the title across every course/group combination and breaks the concept of database normalisation.

You would be better splitting the table into two tables:

```
course
---------
id_course    (Primary Key)
title

course_group
------------
id_course    (FK referencing course) } composite PK
id_groupe    (FK referencing groupe) }
```

Then you can set the title for the course and it is independent of the groups associated with the course. You can, of course, have a composite primary key on the `course_group` table consisting of both ids to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: the (id_course,id_groupe) are both  a composit primary key in course_group table ?

Comment: Yes - since they appear to uniquely identify a course/group pairing. However, you could do: `CREATE TABLE course_group ( id INT PRIMARY KEY, id_course INT NOT NULL REFERENCES course (id_course), id_groupe INT NOT NULL REFERENCES groupe (id_groupe), CONSTRAINT course_group__u UNIQUE ( id_course, id_groupe ) );` if you just want a unique constraint rather than having a composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a course that may be shared by many groups, I'd think of a sligthly different design, with a relation table linking COURSE and GROUPE; this table could have a composite PK, based on the two foreing key columns:

```
COURSE
  id_course PK
  id_module KF references MODULE

MODULE
  id_module PK

GROUPE
  id_groupe PK

COURSE_REL_GROUPE 
  id_course FK references COURSE
  id_groupe FK references GROUPE
    PRIMARY KEY (id__course, id_groupe)
```

Comment: please don't do that, he didn't try anyting .He can't learn via this way